# How to merge splitted zip files in php

Tags: php, zip

I splitted a big .zip file into 5 parts.

bigfile.zip.001

bigfile.zip.002

bigfile.zip.003

bigfile.zip.004

bigfile.zip.005

and i want to merge them, how can do that with PHP ?

Comment: [Here is the PHP ZIP Extension manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) Thats is a good place to start.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, how would you open a splitted archive? The Documentation for `ZipArchive::open` not mention about how to handle a splitted archive.

Comment: Is it not possible just to copy all 5 files into a single file `copy f1+f2+f3+f4+f5 bigfile` Its been years since I split zips like this, but I seem to remember they are basically just chunked.